# Dynamically loading images from database to webpage momentarily messes up how the masterpage looks like

Tags: database, image, master-pages, html

I'm a senior majoring in Computer Science. I'm new at web development. I'm using ASP.NET C# with MS SQL Server. I've been trying to figure out how to load images from the database onto the webpage. I have successfully done this with the following code.

```
<asp:Image ID="imageClient" runat="server" style="width:100px; height:100px;"/>

protected void LoadImage() 
{
    ModelDataContext mdc = new ModelDataContext();

    byte[] image = (from c in mdc.Clients select c.Logo).FirstOrDefault().ToArray();
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(image, 0, image.Length);
    imageClient.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
}
```

Right now I'm just doing it for 1 image. I will eventually be using a repeater to display multiple images on the same page.

The problem is with the loading of the image. It does some weird stuff to the masterpage that it uses. It's as if it isn't applying the CSS to the masterpage. But a few seconds later it looks as it should. The problem is definitely with the loading of the image because there is no other loading problems on any of the other pages.

I tried posting pictures of what I am seeing, but my reputation is too low.

The problem isn't browser specific, it does the same thing in all the major browsers...
If anybody could help me with the problem that would be great.

/*############################*/
Edit: I realized the images that I was trying to view may have had a filesize too large and it was taking too long to get it from the database and to load the image. My new approach is to save the image to a folder within my project and saving the imageurl in the database to refer to the actual location of the image.

Is this the best approach keeping in mind I am nowhere near at being advanced in Web Dev?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching the image to a folder can give you benefits such as reducing load on the database. If the web pages are in a busy environment (ie. many users) caching everything you can reducing the load on the database is desirable.

As to the initial image-tag. As far as I remember, the asp:Image doesn't support a Style tag as with html img tag. I think you would need to define a css in a style-sheet (or embedded in the page) and refer to that with the CssClass tag instead - or - use the .Style("property") = "mysetting" in code instead.

F.ex:

```
imageClient.Style("Width") = "100px"
imageClient.Style("Height") = "100px"
```

Comment: Styling on asp:Image was just a quick fix to show the image. I normally use Class="something" for styling. Regardless, it worked in this case. . ..Thank you for your comment. Doing it this way the image loads faster.  The load of the masterpage is pretty fast, but I can notice that an image that is in the masterpage is displayed before all the javascript and css is applied.